# To_char date in sql only works with wednesday

Tags: sql, oracle, date, where-clause

This query that I made returns the number of employees hired for an specific position in a specific day

```
SELECT job_title ,To_char(hire_date, 'Day') AS HIRE_DAY,
       Count(*)                    AS cc
FROM   employees
WHERE To_char(hire_date,'Day')='Sunday' OR To_char(hire_date,'Day')='Wednesday'
GROUP  BY job_title,To_char(hire_date, 'Day') 
ORDER  BY job_title ASC;
```

Basically this query only works when I type 'Wednesday' in the WHERE clause, Why is this? How can I fix it so it works with Sunday and Saturday

Without the where clause I get

```
Accountant  Friday      1
Accountant  Monday      1
Accountant  Tuesday     1
Accountant  Wednesday   2
Accounting Manager  Tuesday     1
Administration Assistant    Saturday    1
```

and with the where clause I get

```
Accountant  Wednesday   2
Administration Vice President   Wednesday   2
Finance Manager Wednesday   1
Marketing Manager   Wednesday   1
Marketing Representative    Wednesday   1
Purchasing Clerk    Wednesday   2
```

I just don't get any results with any other day

Comment: and which rdms are you using exactly besides provide a [mre] see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Dumb question, but does it not work for Saturday/Sunday because no one is hired on the weekend? Did you try running the query without the WHERE clause to see what days have data?

Comment: I ran it without the where clause and I got every single result, there are people hired on every day but it just does not work with anything other than wednesday

Comment: please add some date and cretae table a dbfiddle would also help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's those two letters: `fm` that make the difference.

```
SQL> with temp (datum) as
  2    (select trunc(sysdate, 'mm') + level - 1
  3     from dual
  4     connect by level <= 7
  5    )
  6  select to_char(datum, 'dd.mm.yyyy, day') datum,
  7         to_char(datum, 'Day') day,
  8         length(to_char(datum, 'Day')) len_day,
  9         --
 10         to_char(datum, 'fmDay') day2,
 11         length(to_char(datum, 'fmDay')) len_day2
 12  from temp;

DATUM                     DAY           LEN_DAY DAY2         LEN_DAY2
------------------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
01.04.2022, friday        Friday              9 Friday              6
02.04.2022, saturday      Saturday            9 Saturday            8
03.04.2022, sunday        Sunday              9 Sunday              6
04.04.2022, monday        Monday              9 Monday              6
05.04.2022, tuesday       Tuesday             9 Tuesday             7
06.04.2022, wednesday     Wednesday           9 Wednesday           9
07.04.2022, thursday      Thursday            9 Thursday            8

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```

As you can see, `len_day` is always the same: `11`, because you used the `'Day'` format model. You should have used `'fmDay'` instead.

---

Or, worse solution, `trim`:

```
SQL> select to_char(sysdate, 'Day') today,
  2         length(to_char(sysdate, 'Day')) len_today,
  3         --
  4         trim(to_char(sysdate, 'Day')) today2,
  5         length(trim(to_char(sysdate, 'Day'))) len_today2
  6  from dual;
    
TODAY                 LEN_TODAY TODAY2               LEN_TODAY2
-------------------- ---------- -------------------- ----------
Monday                        9 Monday                        6

SQL>
```

Comment: Funny, I often use this as an interview question *('How do you check that a specific date falls on a weekend?)* You wouldn't believe how few candidates can answer that. (Follow-up question, *What if the user is in Paris with a French desktop?*)